# unable to SetField ogr OFTDate field, how do I set a OFTDate field

Tags: python, date, gdal, ogr

Im using OGR to create a feature from another feature and write it out, it all seems to work except for the ogr.OFTDate field.

```
out_feature_fields = [
    ogr.FieldDefn("enc", ogr.OFTString),
    ogr.FieldDefn('edition', ogr.OFTInteger),
    ogr.FieldDefn('updno', ogr.OFTInteger),
    ogr.FieldDefn('usage', ogr.OFTInteger),
    ogr.FieldDefn('status', ogr.OFTInteger),
    ogr.FieldDefn('issue_date', ogr.OFTDate)
]

layer_def = ogr.FeatureDefn()
for field_defn in out_feature_fields:
    layer_def.AddFieldDefn(field_defn)

#logging here gives a date 20200601
logging.info(f"in feature {out_feature.GetField('DSID_ISDT')}")

outfeature = ogr.Feature(layer_def)
outfeature.SetGeometry(coverage_geom)
outfeature.SetField('enc', out_feature.GetField('DSID_DSNM')[:-4])
outfeature.SetField('edition', out_feature.GetField('DSID_EDTN'))
outfeature.SetField('updno', out_feature.GetField('DSID_UPDN'))
outfeature.SetField('usage', out_feature.GetField('DSID_DSNM')[2])
outfeature.SetFieldNull('status')
outfeature.SetField('issue_date', out_feature.GetField('DSID_ISDT'))

# logging here gives null
logging.info(f"out feature {outfeature.GetField('issue_date')}")
```

this logs

```
2020-06-29 17:40:08 INFO     in feature 20200611
2020-06-29 17:40:08 INFO     out feature None
```

So Im failing to set the date field and its Null in my output, Im thnking there is something Im missing about setting date fields in ogr but I dont know what and my search efforts have not helped so far.

Comment: tried setting up a datetime.date and pass that in, didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Seems I had to set the date like this

```
feature.SetField('issue_date',  f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
```